# How to solve a system with infinitely many equations?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

I need to solve the following system of (infinitely many) equations. I am looking for $V(0,0)$

- $t \in \{0,1,2.....\}$ with one caveat that $s \leq 1+t$ should hold.
- $ s \in \{1,2,3,L-1\}$
- fixed parameters are in $L$ (Integer), $a$, $b$, $c$ and $h(<1)$

  \begin{array}{rlllllll}
  V(0,t) & = a+h V(1,t+1) \\
  V(s,t+1) & = \frac{s}{t+1} (b + h V(s-1,t+2))+ (1-\frac{s}{1+t}) (a+ h V(s+1,t+2)) & 
  \text{for $s \in \{1,...,L-1\}$}\\ 
  V(L,t+1)& = \frac{L}{t+1} b + (1-\frac{L}{1+t}) c + h V(L-1,t+2)
  \end{array}

Comment: Shouldn't s <= t instead of s >=t?

Comment: true. I was in rush to post!

Comment: You can try to rewrite the system as a partial differential equation (PDE) and subsequently solve it with `NDSolve`

Comment: Can NDSolve produce symbolic solutions? I don't know how to do that.

Comment: NDSolve provides only numerical solutions

Comment: Can you please fix the non-matching parentheses in the definition of $V(s,t+1)$?

Comment: I fixed it, sorry for that

Comment: This seems like an `RSolve` problem! Not sure if `RSolve` will actually succeed though.